# How can you check if there is the same item in an array and do something otherwise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to push items to an array but I want that if there's a similar item in an array, to just update the count to 1 and not add the item another time on the array. I've tried plenty of things such as the `include()` function but it is not working as expected, because when I put item.includes(product) as I'm mapping through each product, whenever I add an item, the count gets updated for each product... For example when I add one product, for one item, another item also gets that update...

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import data from './data.js'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function Shop({ data }) {
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const {item, setItem} = useContext(useCountsContext)

  const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {
       if (item.includes(product)) {
         product.count += 1
       }  else if (product.id === productsId) {
          setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
      })
  }
console.log(item)

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
              <div key={id}>
                <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

my data file:

```
import diCaprio from './img/diCaprio.jpg'
import steveJobs from './img/steveJobs.jpg'
import lips from './img/lips.jpg'
import buda from './img/buda.jpg'
import spaceDog from './img/spaceDog.jpg'
import astroNube from './img/astroNube.jpg'
import banksy from './img/Banksy.jpg'
import banksyDJ from './img/banksyDJ.jpg'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');


const data = [{
  id: uniqid(),
  title: "Steve Jobs",
  img: steveJobs,
  homeImg: steveJobs,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: diCaprio,
  homeImg: diCaprio,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: lips,
  homeImg: lips,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: buda,
  homeImg: buda,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: spaceDog,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:astroNube,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: banksy,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:banksyDJ,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
}
]

export default data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` is a list (array) of products and `product` is an object.
you cannot use `includes` on an array which contains objects, you can use a general `for` loop, `forEach`, or modern `find` to search for product in your items array

```js
const addCart = (productsId) => {
    setCount(count + 1)
    data.forEach((product) => {
        const exists = item.findIndex((i) => i.id === product.id) > -1;
        // if check is on title
        // const exists = item.findIndex((i) => i.title === product.title) > -1;
        if (exists) {
            product.count += 1
        } else if (product.id === productsId) {
            setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
    })
}
```

Update after OP's comment

```js
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import data from './data.js'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function Shop({ data }) {
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const {item, setItem} = useContext(useCountsContext)

  const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      // grab the product object from data array
      const product = data.find((d) => d.id === productsId);
      // if product is not found
      if (product == null) {
          throw new Error("Invalid ProductId");
      }
      // check if product already exists in item list
      // grab the index of the product in the item list
      const exists = item.findIndex((i) => i.id === product.id);
      // if index is -1, the product doesn't exists
      if (exists === -1) {
        // add to item array
        setItem(item.concat(product));
      } else {
        // product already exists
        // increase the count
        const cart = [...item]; // create a Shallow copy of cart
        cart[exists].count += 1; // increment the count
        setItem(cart); // update the cart state
      }
  }

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
              <div key={id}>
                <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

Comment: it still adds the product whenever I click another one

Comment: for example if i add steve jobs it adds one, but when I add dicaprio it adds two to the steve jobs aswell

Comment: currently the check is on `product.id`

Comment: you can use `i.title  === product.title`

Comment: there is no title in my product data

Comment: I can see title Steve Jobs in your first item. Leave it. What is unique in your data? How do you know if same product is chosen more than once?

Comment: the id is unique as it generates one from uniqid

Comment: I've added a complete solution, let me know if this works for you.